# ip to country database or api

Tags: geolocation, ip-geolocation

I'm developing an analytics website and I need a powerful and the most up to date database of IP addresses and countries ISO (us, fr, tn, ca...). I found a lot out there but I can't pick out the best one.

Anyone to advise me please?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using the [MaxMind's GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) at the company, they have libraries for multiple languages, free and commercial licenses.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it as suggested by those earlier. But I suggest you take a look at the IP2 PHP library available at https://github.com/ip2iq/ip2-lib-php which we developed.

It doesn't need any SQL or web service lookup just a local data file. It is faster than almost all other methods out there. The database is updated monthly you can download it for free.

The only thing you will need to do for now if you need the country name in your language is map it to an associative array from something like this https://gist.github.com/DHS/1340150

Answer (score 0):

Download the mysql table from http://www.ip2nation.com/ if you are looking for a **free** & simple to use solution.